# dhtmlx grid : How to know big data is loaded when i use enableDistributedParsing or enableSmartRendering

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx

I use dhtmlx to build grid in my project. `enableDistributedParsing` or `enableSmartRendering` are ways to load big data, dom table cell nodes will be append to grid table.

But after I check the event list of dhtmlx, I cant find anyone to bind to the loaded event.

How could I know the big data have been loaded? And how could I bind new events to the lines which is appended to the grid table before all data have been loaded?

follow is my example code:

```
var grid = new dhtmlXGridObject(container_id);
grid.setImagePath("/AM/img/");
grid.enableTreeCellEdit(false);
grid.enableAutoWidth(true);
grid.enableAutoHeight(true);
grid.enableDistributedParsing(true,100,250);
grid.parse(data,'json');

$('#' + container_id).find('.objbox tr').hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
},function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});

// well, how to bind hover to `tr` after new lines appended to table?
```

Anyone helps?

Answer (score 0):

Check for onXLE grid event that fires right after data is loaded to the grid. You can fire a call there if you want to manipulated newly loaded grid rows.
Hope this will help.

Comment: well, it says onXLE fires simultaneously with ending XML parsing, new items are already available in grid.
I load data from json, does this work? 
I didn't try, and will take for a test. Thanks any way.